# What does the expression (define (f x) (length (range 3000))) evaluate to?

Tags: racket, evaluate

For the expression

```
(define x (length (range 3000)))
```

I think it is evaluated to

```
(define x 3000)
```

For the expression

```
(define (f x) (length (range 3000)))
```

Does it evaluate to the following as well?

```
(define (f x) 3000)
```

Comment: To answer the question in the title: the expression `(define (f x) ...)` evaluates to a _procedure_ object, which will only return `3000` after you actually _call_ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they evaluate to two different procedures, with different bodies. A completely different matter is that when executed, they both will return the same value, namely `3000`, ignoring the parameter in both cases. To be clear, the first expression binds `f` to a `lambda` (this is how `define` expands a procedure definition under the hood):

```
(define f
  (lambda (x) (length (range 3000))))
```

The second expression also binds `f` to a `lambda`, but it's a different one:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x) 3000))
```

Either one will return `3000` when invoked:

```
(f 42)
=> 3000
```

But the first one will do more work, it has to create a `range` and calculate its `length`, whereas the second one simply returns `3000`. Regarding your first example - in the end `x` will have the same value, and it won't matter how you calculated it. But for the second example, the two `f`s are different objects, even though the values they calculate are the same.

Comment: Did you explain `(define (f x) (length (range 3000)))`? I'm confused. Sorry

Comment: I explained your second example, read it again please. I'm answering the question in the post: "Does it evaluate to the following as well?"

Comment: TL;DR : no, they evaluate to different _procedures_ even though their values appear to be the same when invoked. `f` is a procedure, `x` is a value.

Comment: Ummm, not sure if I get it. So is `(define (f x) (length (range 3000)))`  kind of lazy evaluation? In your explanation, `(define f
  (lambda (x) (length (range 3000))))` it won't evaluate `(length (range 3000))` untill the function being called, isn't it?

Comment: It is not lazy evaluation, you're defining two different functions, each with a parameter and a body. It doesn't have a value until you call it, it's the same as any other programming language, functions are just a series of instructions, they are evaluated and return a value (if any) only when invoked.

Comment: Ah, yea. Thank you for ur help & patient.